# How to return true=1 or false=0 when updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_Erp_Branch_Update] 
    @Id int, 
    @Code varchar(20),
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @IsActive bit=1,
    @UpdateBy varchar(50),
    @ImgId int
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT* FROM Branch WHERE Id = @id AND IsDelete =0)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Branch 
        SET Code = ISNULL(@Code,Code),
            Name = ISNULL( @Name,Name),
            IsActive = ISNULL( @IsActive,IsActive),
            UpdatedBy = ISNULL( @UpdateBy,UpdatedBy),
            ImageId = ISNULL( @ImgId,ImageId)
            output deleted.Id
        WHERE Id = @Id AND IsDelete = 0
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 0
    END
END
```

Why does the procedure always return 0 even though the update statement appears to be successful in the `[dbo].[Proc_Erp_Branch_Update]`?

How do I resolve this?

```
var query = "Proc_Erp_Position_Update"; 

var res = await con.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>(query, new { Id = model.Id, Code = model.Code, Name = model.Name, IsAtive = model.IsActive, UpdatBy = username, ImageId = imgid.HasValue? imgid : 0 }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

return res;
```

`res` always returns 0

Comment: Do you mean the return value of the stored procedure?  If you want a specific value to be  returned as the result of the stored proc call, you should use RETURN 0 or RETURN 1.  Currently, you have 2 things happening - an UPDATE statement that runs, but then no subsequent SELECT or RETURN statement after the update - or, your "SELECT 0" statement (which will be outputting a row of data, but not actually affecting the "return result" of the stored proc call)

Comment: No idea what you are asking, please ensure you ask a clear question on what you want assistance with.

Comment: And I suspect you don't need all those `1.` in your question... Nor does `C#` seem relevant to the question.

Comment: And you don't need an `IF` statement, if you need to test whether anything was inserted just test `@@rowcount` after your update.

Comment: var query = "Proc_Erp_Position_Update";
                var res = await con.QueryFirstAsync<int>(query, new
                {
                    Id = model.Id,
                    Code = model.Code,
                    Name =  model.Name,
                    IsAtive = model.IsActive,
                    UpdatBy = username,
                    ImageId = imgid.HasValue? imgid : 0
                }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                return res; but res always ==0 when update successful

Comment: Is `QueryFirstAsync` Dapper or .NET? And what does the documentation say the return value is? I think you need to call something more like `ExecuteSqlAsync` and then check how to return a value, because as the first comment on your question explains there are multiple ways to return values from a SP.

Comment: I need to check update true or false

Comment: @hungjrocho - use a RETURN statement in your stored proc to return a result to your C# call.  By default, if you do not have different RETURN statements in your proc (that are returning different values), a call to the stored proc will always result in zero (0)

Answer (score 0):

`res` will always be 0 since if your procedure does find the row and update it, it will not select any value - and the default for int in dot net is 0.

However, there is another problem in your procedure - there is a chance, though admittedly a small chance, that the relevant row will be changed or deleted between the select statement in the `exists` condition and the `update` statement that follows.

Luckily, there's an easy fix for that - simply remove the `if`.
Executing a stored procedure will return, by default, the number of rows effected, so you can simply use `con.ExecuteAsync` to get that number.

SQL:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_Erp_Branch_Update] 
    @Id int, 
    @Code varchar(20),
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @IsActive bit=1,
    @UpdateBy varchar(50),
    @ImgId int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Branch 
        SET Code = ISNULL(@Code,Code),
            Name = ISNULL( @Name,Name),
            IsActive = ISNULL( @IsActive,IsActive),
            UpdatedBy = ISNULL( @UpdateBy,UpdatedBy),
            ImageId = ISNULL( @ImgId,ImageId)
    WHERE Id = @Id AND IsDelete = 0
END
```

C#:

```cs
var query = "Proc_Erp_Position_Update"; 

var res = await con.ExecuteAsync(query, new { Id = model.Id, Code = model.Code, Name = model.Name, IsAtive = model.IsActive, UpdatBy = username, ImageId = imgid.HasValue? imgid : 0 }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

return res;
```

Note: I'm assuming you're using c# and Dapper based on the code you've shown in your question.